# Assign Linestring to Polygon based on Max length

Tags: pandas, geopandas, shapely

I have two geopandas dataframes one is Linestring and other is Polygon. I need to assign the Linestring to Polygon based on Max length. The plot of them looks below.The two polygons are separated by edge color which is Balck.
[image]

I am using the following code to assign Linestring to Polygon

```
well_segments = gpd.overlay(Polygons,Linestring, how='intersection')
well_segments['segment_length'] = well_segments.length
well_segments["geometry"] = well_segments.geometry.to_wkt()
well_segments_df = spark.createDataFrame(well_segments)
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("api12").orderBy(col("segment_length").desc())
well_segments_valid_df = well_segments_df.select("API", "ID", f.row_number().over(windowSpec).alias("rn"), "segment_length", "geometry").filter(f.col("rn") == 1)
```

Is there any  most efiicient way of doing it in Geopandas or Pandas

Comment: What do you mean by assign based on max length? What do you actually want in your output dataframe?

Comment: the bottom polygon contains max length of line string. so in that case the Linestring belongs to that polygon.

Comment: I see. you want to assign each linestring to a single polygon based on which polygon contains the largest overlapped length. and you have a valid implementation in spark and you're just looking for us to translate it to geopandas for you? have you tried? seems like a simple groupby argmax would do the trick

Comment: yeah i would like it to translate into Geopandas to make simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you have not provided any sample data.  So have used some polygons from natural earth dataset and generated 5 lines which will be of different lengths in each to these polygons
- the actual solution is:

  - use `sjoin()` instead of `overlay()`
  - filter down line with greatest length for each polygon (`index_right`)

```
    longest = (
        gpd.sjoin(linestrings, polygons, predicate="intersects")
        .assign(len=lambda d: d["geometry"].length)
        .sort_values(["index_right", "len"])
        .groupby("index_right")["geometry"]
        .last()
    )
```

##@ full working code ###

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString
import numpy as np
import folium
import warnings

r = np.random.RandomState(22)
polygons = (
    gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
    .loc[lambda d: d["geometry"].type.eq("Polygon") & d["continent"].eq("Africa")]
    .sample(5, random_state=r)
    .loc[:, ["geometry"]]
)

lss = (
    polygons.exterior.apply(
        lambda g: np.array(g.coords)[r.choice(len(g.coords), [5, 2])]
    )
    .explode()
    .apply(LineString)
)
linestrings = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=lss, crs=polygons.crs).reset_index(drop=True)

# find the longest line in each polygon
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    longest = (
        gpd.sjoin(linestrings, polygons, predicate="intersects")
        .assign(len=lambda d: d["geometry"].length)
        .sort_values(["index_right", "len"])
        .groupby("index_right")["geometry"]
        .last()
    )

longest = gpd.GeoSeries(longest, crs=polygons.crs)

# visualise it...
m = polygons.explore(height=300, width=600, color="cyan", name="polys")
m = linestrings.explore(m=m, name="all lines", color="blue", style_kwds={"weight":.8})
m = longest.explore(m=m, name="longest", color="red")
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

[image]